# При вычитании таймштампов в цикле, в терминал валятся ошибки

Tags: bash

Если в Bash выполнить

```
let RAZNOST="$(stat -c %Y /dir1/$file) - $(stat -c %Y /dir1/dir2/$file)"
```

то мы получим разность таймштампов, все работает корректно, всё хорошо.

Но если выполнять эту команду внутри цикла, то в терминале куча ошибок вида -

> 1609183561: синтаксическая ошибка в выражении (неверный маркер
> «1609183561 1609183561 1609183561 1609183561 1609183561 1609183561
> 1609183561 1609183561 1609183561 1609183561 - 1609183544 1609183561
> 1609183561 1609183561 1609183561 1609183561 1609183561 1609183561
> 1609183561 1609183561 1609183561»)

При этом цикл отработает нормально, мы получим верный ответ.

```
            while IFS= read -r l ;

            do

            file=$(grep -o "$l" <(echo "$A1"))

            if  [  $? -eq "0" ] ; then

                   let  X="$(stat -c %Y /dir1/$file) - $(stat -c %Y /dir1/dir2.$file)"
                      if [ "$X" -ge 120 ];then
                            ...
                            do something
                            ...                
                            
                     fi
            else
                    ...
                    do something else
                    ...
            fi

            done < <(echo "$R")
```

*Это мой первый код в Bash очень хочется понять*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ошибка у вас состоит в том, что в переменной `$file` находится несколько слов.

в результате программа *stat* получает несколько аргументов. и возвращает несколько значений. пример:

```
$ file="/bin /etc"
$ stat -c %Y $file
1607256826
1609133548
```

соответственно вместо такого корректного арифметического выражения:

```
let x="число1 - число2"
```

вы получаете примерно такое некорректное арифметическое выражение (в приведённом вами примере у вас чисел значительно больше):

```
let x="число1 число2 - число3 число4"
```

на что получаете вполне справедливое сообщение об ошибке:

> bash: let: x=число1 число2 - число3 число4: syntax error in expression (error token is "число2 - число3 число4")

---

вероятно, вам стоит использовать ещё один (вложенный) цикл для перебора значений, возвращаемых командой `grep -o "$l" <(echo "$A1")`. что-нибудь вроде:

```
files=$(grep -o "$l" <(echo "$A1"))
for file in $files; do
  ...
done
```

---

а ещё вместо `let` можно использовать «нормальное» вычисление арифметического выражения. т.е. вместо:

```
let x="арифметическое выражение"
```

использовать:

```
x=$((арифметическое выражение))
```

Comment: Я думал, что в переменную $file попадает лишь одно совпадение текущей строки из цикла $l **- текущая страка из многострочной переменной $R, которая построчно читается в while**   и результата команды , grep -o "$l" <(echo "$A1") **Это совпадение строки в многострочной переменной $A1** Вы не могли бы обьяснить как туда попадают несколько значений?

Comment: элементарно. если в том файле, имя которого содержится в переменной `$A1`, будет найдено несколько совпадений, то вашей командой будут выведены все. проверьте: `$ echo "123 123" | grep -o "123"` — выдаст два совпадения.

Comment: А совпадений то быть не должно,  в каждой переменной значения уникальны у каждой есть номер 1,2,3..150

Comment: *совпадений то быть не должно* — это уж вы сами разбирайтесь в своих исходных данных. подсказка: воспользуйтесь командой `echo $переменная` для контроля, что же находится в переменной.

Comment: Я как раз   в цикле добавил после каждой итерации echo, но каких то проблем не увидел. Но все равно большое спасибо,  буду копать в этом направлении

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)